# Fourier transform of $\exp(-x^TAx)$

Tags: fourier-transform, bilinear-form

Given $A$ symmetric, positive definite. Calculate 
$$\hat f(\omega)=\frac{1}{2\pi^{n/2}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \exp(-x^TAx) \exp(-i\omega^Tx) \, dx$$

My approach: using $D=VAV^T$, $D$ diagonal matrix, $x=V^Ty$
one get
$$ \hat f(\omega) = \frac{1}{2\pi^{n/2}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \exp(-y^TDy) \exp(-i\omega^TV^Ty) det(V) \, dy$$

I am actually a bit stuck here, I could write $$\exp(-y^TDy) \exp(-i\omega^TV^Ty) = \exp(-y^TDy-i\omega^Ty) $$
but since the first term is bilinear, I am not sure how to proceed "optimally". I am very thankful for hints.

edit: $det(V)=1$ 
Greetings.

Comment: Perhaps you should apply another change invariable:  take $k := V\omega$

Comment: I actually thought about that, but it doenst bring me any further. Maybe one should take this as an parameter dependend integral, so after differentiating under the integral is possible, I am not sure that this is possible/necessary (multidimensional case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $D = \operatorname{diag}(d_1, \ldots, d_n)$ we have 
$$
\exp(-y^TDy) 
= \exp(-\sum_{k=1}^{n} d_k y_k^2) 
= \prod_{k=1}^{n} \exp(-d_k y_k^2).
$$

Setting $\tilde\omega = V\omega$ we also have 
$$
\exp(-i\omega^T V^T y) 
= \exp(-i\tilde\omega^T y) 
= \exp\left(-i \sum_{k=1}^{n} \tilde\omega_k y_k \right)
= \prod_{k=1}^{n} \exp\left(-i \tilde\omega_k y_k \right)
$$

Therefore,
$$
\int_{\mathbb R^n} \exp(-y^TDy) \exp(-i\omega^T V^T y) \, dy \\
= \int_{\mathbb R^n} \prod_{k=1}^{n} \exp(-d_k y_k^2) \prod_{k=1}^{n} \exp\left(-i \tilde\omega_k y_k \right) \, dy \\
= \int_{\mathbb R^n} \prod_{k=1}^{n} \left( \exp(-d_k y_k^2) \exp\left(-i \tilde\omega_k y_k \right) \right) \, dy \\
= \prod_{k=1}^{n} \int_{\mathbb R} \left( \exp(-d_k y_k^2) \exp\left(-i \tilde\omega_k y_k \right) \right) \, dy \\
= \prod_{k=1}^{n} \exp(- \tilde\omega^2/(4 d_k)) \\
= \exp(- \sum_{k=1}^{n} \tilde\omega^2/(4 d_k)) \\
= \exp(- \frac14 \tilde\omega^T D^{-1} \tilde\omega) \\
= \exp(- \frac14 \omega^T V^T D^{-1} V \omega) \\
= \exp(- \frac14 \omega^T A^{-1} \omega)
$$

Answer (score 1):

I presume that you have taken $V$ to be orthogonal, so that $V^T = V^{-1}$. So far, we have (noting that $\det(V) = 1$)
$$
\hat f(\omega) = \frac{1}{2\pi^{n/2}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \exp(-y^TDy) \exp(-i\omega^TV^Ty) \, dy
$$
Now, let $g(x) = \exp(-x^TDx)$.
With the substitution $k = V \omega$, we can write
$$
\hat f(\omega) = \frac{1}{2\pi^{n/2}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \exp(-y^TDy) \exp(-i\omega^TV^Ty) \, dy 
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi^{n/2}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \exp(-y^TDy) \exp(-ik^Ty) \, dy 
\\ = \hat g(k) = \hat g(V\omega)
$$
That is: once you've calculated $\hat g(\omega)$, you can calculate $\hat f(\omega) = \hat g(V\omega)$.

---

Another hint: suppose that
$$
D = \pmatrix{d_1\\&\ddots \\&&d_n}
$$
with the careful application of some Fubini magic, we find that
$$
\hat g(\omega) = \frac{1}{2\pi^{n/2}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \exp(-x^TDx) \exp(-i\omega^Tx) \, dx 
\\ = 
\frac{1}{2\pi^{n/2}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \left(\prod_{j=1}^{n}\exp^{-d_jx_j^2 }\exp^{- i\omega_j x_j} \right) dx
\\ =  
\frac{1}{2\pi^{n/2}} \prod_{j=1}^{n}\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}\exp^{-d_jx_j^2 - i\omega_j x_j}dx_j \right)
$$
So, it suffices to answer the question in the 1-D case.

Comment: thank you. Unfortunaly g(x) is exactly were I stuck. for n=1 we would have something like the fourier of the gaussian "distributation". How do I tackle that in multidim.?

Comment: @user160069 Well, you do need to handle the $n = 1$ case!  You should find that the transform of a Gaussian is itself a Gaussian.  In the case that $D$ is diagonal, you should find that the integral can be "decoupled" into the product of 1-D transforms.

Comment: See my latest edit